# How do I solve this infinite intersection of closed sets problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]
$$
What is this set? I need some explanation as well. I'm a beginning calculus student. I know real numbers are uncountable, and that may have something to do with this problem.

I was thinking $[0, 2]$ is the solution, but *$s$* can't be $0$. So what is it?

Comment: Your answer should not have $s$ in it. $s$ is the dummy variable.

Comment: With $I_s:= [-s,s+2]$, the intersection of all $I_s$ is a subset of each $I_s$, for example is a subset of $I_{0.001}=[-0.001,2.001]$. Can you guess what the intersection ultimately is?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. I meant that I thought the solution might be [0, 2].

Comment: Well, let's see.   If $0 \le x \le 2$ then does it follow that $-s \le x \le s+2$ for all positive $s$.   .... Well $-s < 0$ and $0 \le x$.  And $s+2 > 2$ and $2\ge x$ so, yes, for any positive $s$ we do have $-s\le x \le x+2$ so $[0,2]\subset \cap_{s\in\mathbb R^+}[-s,s+2]$.  ... Now if $x < 0$ or $x > 2$ does it stop being true?  If $x < 0$ and then there is a $w$ so that $x < w < 0$ and if we let $s=|w|$ then $x < w=-s$ so $x\not \in [-s,s+2]$ so $x \not \in  \cap_{s\in\mathbb R^+}[-s,s+2]$.  Do something similar for $x > 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to think of this is that if $x \in \bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]$ then $-s \le x \le s + x$ for all $s > 0$.

So $x > -s$.  So what numbers are greater than *any* possible negative number.   Well any non negative number well do.  If $x \ge 0$ then for any positive $s$ we have $-s < 0$ so $x \ge 0 > -s$ so any positive $x$ will do.

And *no* negative number will do.  If $x < 0$ then we con find some $w$ so that $x < w < 0$ and if we let $s =|w| > 0$, we have $x < -s$.

So *only* $x\ge 0$ will be so that $x > -s$ for all $s> 0$ and *every* $x \ge 0$ will be so that $x > -s$ for all $s$.

And using the same reasoning...

$x \le s + 2$ for *every* positive number number $s$.  If $x \le 2$ we will have $x \le 2 < s + 2$ is certainly true.

And if $x > 2$ that will be false.  If $x > 2$ there will exist a $w$ so that $2 < w < x$ and if we let $s = w-2 > 0$ then we have $s+2 = w-2 + 2 = w < x$.

So every $x \le 2$ and only $x \le 2$ will be so that $x \le s+2$ for all $s > 0$.

So only $0 \le x \le 2$ will be so that $-s \le x \le s+2$ for all possible $s > 0$ and *every* $x: 0 \le x \le 2$ will be so that $-s\le x \le s+2$ for all possible $s> 0$.

So $\bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2] = [0,2]$.

......

Alternatively......  If $M \subset A_\alpha$ for every $A_\alpha$ then $M\subset \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$.

(Do you see that?  If we have a bunch of sets $A_\alpha$ and $M$ is a subset of each and every one of them, then for every $x \in M$ then $x$ will be an element of each and every $A_\alpha$.  So $x$ will be an element of the intersections of all $A_\alpha$.  So $M \subset \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$.  A subtle, but irrelevant aspect of this is that we can have an infinite and even uncountable number of these sets $A_\alpha$.)

So as $-s < 0$ and $2 < s+2$ for all $s > 0$ we have $[0,2]\subset [-s, s+2]$ for all $s > 0$.  So $[0,2] \subset \bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]$

Now suppose $x\in \bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]$

If we assume $x > 2$ we get a contradiction.  Let $s$ be such that $0 < s < x-2$ and we have $s+2 < x-2 +2 = x$ so $x \not \in [-s, s+2]$.

So $x \le 2$.

Similarly if $x < 0$ we get a contradiction.  Let $s$ be such that $0 < s < |x|$ and we have $-s < x$ and $x\not \in [-s, s+2]$.

So of $x \in \bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]$ then $x \in [0,2]$.

So $\bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2]\subset [0,2]$.

So $\bigcap_{s\in \mathbb R^+} [-s, s+2] = [0,2]$